# Customizing dialog by extending Dialog or AlertDialog

Tags: android, customization, android-dialog, android-theme

I want to make a custom `Dialog`. Because I don't like its style, I want to have rounded rectangle rather than sharp corners. I know how to implement it by theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`, for example, I use:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomDialog"
```

And `Theme.CustomDialog.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.CustomDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/filled_box</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

filled_box.xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" color="#ffff8080"/>
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

How can I implement a similar result by extending the `Dialog` or `AlertDialog`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In the constructor of your class that extends Dialog call `super(context, R.style.CustomDialog);`  I've done this many times to create custom dialogs with specific themes.

However if the theme is the only thing about the Dialog that you want to change, you could try just instantiating an instance of the Dialog class and pass it the theme ID like `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.CustomDialog);`

An example of extending Dialog:

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog
{
    public MyDialog(final Context context)
    {
        // Set your theme here
        super(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme);

        // This is the layout XML file that describes your Dialog layout
        this.setContentView(R.layout.myDialogLayout);  
    }
}
```

The rest of the code you will add to this class is going to be pretty much exactly like what you would write in an Activity class.

Comment: yes ,thank you for your help .i used  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.CustomDialog),the work very well.
but I cannot write extends Dialog ,can you give me some Code snippets

Comment: I added an example of extending Dialog.

Comment: is it possible to set positive and negative buttons like we do in Dialog? i:e
  
    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            // Positive button clicked
                            getActivityInstance().onOkClicked(GeneralDialogFragment.this);
                        }
                    }

Comment: If dialog is desired **NOT on full screen** just use:

`public MyDialog(final Context context)    {
        super(context);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.myDialogLayout);  
    }`