# Apply the Android "Dialog" theme and sizing it properly

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity that I would like to occur in a dialog.  Is there anyway to do this from code, instead of in the manifest?  I tried to do this, but it seemed to have no effect.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Dialog);
}
```

Also, the activity contains a webview and when it starts out as a dialog it's got a small amount of content and the dialog is only like 100px tall.  When content fills in it scrolls inside a tiny 100px tall window in the dialog.  How do I make the dialog take up more vertical space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this via XML. Just use an XML named 'themes.xml', and place it in the values folder.

Here's a basic example, which implements a custom background:

```
<resources>
    <style name="my_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/custom_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You'll also need to add the following line to the desired activity section of the manifest:

```
 android:theme="@style/my_theme"
```

PS: I realize this is an old thread, but hopefully it helps someone nonetheless  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to set the dialog theme from code.

The dialog is basically as big as it needs to be to contain the content, so if you want it to be bigger you need to make some component in your view larger.  Perhaps you can set the hieght of the webview to something larger.  Note, use dpi, not px!

Answer (score 0):

**that's the solution**, you can **apply a theme via code**, thanks to this guy :)
wasn't aware of this constructor myself

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975508/371749