# Custom row Layout for a Multiple Choice Dialog

Tags: android, listview, layout, dialog, checkedtextview

I would like to implement a `Custom Multiple Choice Dialog`, so following the directions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281945/multiple-choice-alert-dialog-with-custom-row-layout), this is what I did:

I created the `xml` for my row, which is a `CheckedTextView`

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Now, my `Dialog`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setAdapter(
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        R.layout.dialog_list_item, tables), null)
        // Set the action buttons
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

alerDialog.show();
```

As you can see, I have not implemented an `setOnItemClickListener` yet, but I do not know how though. However, the `Dialog` looks fine. How can I call a ClickListener for each of the `CheckedTextView`?

Than you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that @Rahul Gupta suggested works after implementing a `ListView` and `OnItemClickListener`, but if the `ListView` contains too many items, the `Views` that are not shown are going to be "checked" as well. I suppose the `Views` are not yet generated until the user actually scrolls down and see the rest of the items.

The way that I made it work was creating a `Layout` with a single `ListView` and setting the value of `choice mode` to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`. In that case, I don't have to deal with each item, but I can retrieve an array of the items selected by using `listview.getCheckedItemPositions()`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View view= li.inflate(R.layout.listview_dialog, null);
builder.setView(view);
builder.setTitle(title);

listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_list_item , R.id.text2, tables);
listView.setAdapter(ad);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
listView.setDivider(null);

builder.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement thee onClickListener for your `CheckedTextView`.

You just have to find its reference. Now as it is in your dialog, you will have to do this :-

```
CheckedTextView dialogCheckedTextView = (CheckedTextView ) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.yourcheckedtextboxid);
dialogCheckedTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     //TODO
    }
 });
```

Comment: `NullPointerException` at `dialogCheckedTextView.setOnClickListener....` Any ideas?

Comment: This is how you do it only. Check that you passeed the correct reference

Comment: I made it work implementing it inside `listview.setOnItemClickListener...`. However, it gave a different problem at the end and I had to change the implementation. At the end I found a way that works better for my case. Thanks though.