# Custom Dialog extends Dialog not rendering layout by onCreate is executed

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I am trying to create a custom Dialog using the following implementation.

The **problem** is Android is not rendering the layout even though I do set the layout with [setContentView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog#setContentView(int)).

Example of when [.show()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#show()) is called:

[image: Example Problem]

I searched for a possible solution. It appears most use [AlertDialog.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder) although I opted for another easier and reusable route i.e. `ProgressDialog`. Also, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974887/customizing-dialog-by-extending-dialog-or-alertdialog) suggest to place the layout resource on the constructor - which I am skeptical of, but naturally did not work.

**Code files below:**

The source file **ProgressDialog.java**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.example.android.R;

public class ProgressDialog extends Dialog {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView textView;

    public ProgressDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarDialog);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.progressBarText);
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress){
        if (progressBar != null) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

and with the **progress_dialog.xml** layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progressBarText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarDialog"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBarText" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What is causing this problem, why does Android not render the dialog content?

**Update from @md-asaduzzaman's comment**

How to use:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog (SomeActivityHere.this);
dialog.show();

// optional
dialog.setProgress(0);
dialog.setText(getString(R.string.someString));
```

*Alternatively one can pass in a bundle of arguments*

Comment: How to use this dialog?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman see update

Comment: Change your <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  to Linear layout and provide particulate weight to linear layout
In my opinion problem is in constraintlayout.

Comment: @TarunSharma that solves the problem. Could you please post this as the solution including details about its workings, why it doesn't work with a constraint layout, etc

Comment: the problem is there in width = "0dp" provide         android:layout_width="32dp"

Comment: can you please upvote my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem of your `layout`. Change `layout_width` of your view from `0dp` to `wrap_content` or `match_parent` or any fixed size according your requiremnet.

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

**Beside this** your Dialog is not work as expected as `setProgress` and `setText` execute before the dialog created. So, Change your dialog implementation like below:

```
public class ProgressDialog extends Dialog {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView textView;

    private String mText;
    private int mProgress;


    public ProgressDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarDialog);
        progressBar.setProgress(mProgress);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.progressBarText);
        textView.setText(mText);
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress){
        mProgress = progress;

        if (progressBar != null) {
            progressBar.setProgress(mProgress);
        }
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        mText = text;

        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setText(mText);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The layout is loaded, but custom dialog requires fixed height and width if a style theme has not been set. Quick solution is to set both height and width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/progressBarText"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      />

  <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progressBarDialog"
      style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBarText"
      />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also :

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.show();

    // optional
    dialog.setProgress(0);
    dialog.setText("testing");
```

Comment: That depends on whether a fix design (size) is required for all the screens

Answer (score 0):

the Problem is in **android:layout_width="0dp"** 
        change it to particular size like 100dp or match parent

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progressBarText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarDialog"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBarText" />
      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```